# Blank Allure report

Tags: maven, automation, automated-tests, allure

I'm using Allure report tool with Maven+TestNG, but get an empty template. Can't understand what's wrong. Could someone explain why is this happened? 
[image]

There is my pom file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SeleniumTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>1.5.4</allure.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
    <version>${allure.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-BETA14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
        <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
            <argLine>
                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
            </argLine>
            <!--only for 1.3.* TestNG adapters. Since 1.4.0.RC4, the listener adds via ServiceLoader-->
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>listener</name>
                    <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
        </project>
```

I do clean test site and after that io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:serve.

There are console output:
first command results
[image]
[image]

second command result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a misconfiguration. You've mixed up 2 different versions of Allure, including adaptors. Check the official [Allure docs](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_testng).